# strtotime() DateTime class analog method

Tags: php

Is there a method of `DateTime` class which acts like `strtotime()` core PHP function?

For example `strtotime('last monday');`

Comment: Yes, `$date = new DateTime('2012-01-25 19:44:49.123'); echo $dt->getTimestamp();`.

Comment: @deceze I guess in a way of the value it returns...

Comment: @shady Or the value it accepts. Impossible to tell without clarification.

Comment: @deceze That's also true :-D

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That would be `DateTime::__construct`:

```
$date = new DateTime('Sunday');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `DateTime` constructor doesn't have a `$now` parameter like `strtotime` does. Is there any other way how to tell the constructor which is the date to compute against?

Comment: `(new DateTime('now'))->modify('+5 days')`

Comment: to get timestamp for "now" I simply did  $date = new \DateTime('now');
        $now = $date->getTimestamp();

Comment: @Oleksii Or, you know... `time()`.

Answer (score 10):

As `strtotime()` returns long UNIX timestamp, the DateTime has the method `getTimestamp()`.

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-01-25 19:44:49.123');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: This replicates strtotime()'s output well. An alternative is `(new DateTime('2012-01-25 19:44:49.123'))->format('U');`

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `DateTime.createFromFormat()`

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: `createFromFormat()` isn't much like `strtotime()` at all. The latter takes an almost infinite variety of times/dates, including relative ones like `next Sunday` and `Dec. first` whereas the user must specify an exact format to be parsed with the former.