# Get date of this week thursday OR next week thursday in php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I need to get the DATE of this week's Thursday (or any other day) OR next week's Thursday (or any other day)

The scenario is that there are 3 tours happening every week.. I need to find out next tour date

If today is tuesday and date is 21/01/2014 and tours happen on tuesday, friday and sunday.. then I need to find out next tour date which will be on friday on friday

Similarly, if today is Friday, I'll need to find out date on next week's tuesday.

So far, I tried using `strtotime("next tuesday")` but it doesn't seem to work well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo strtotime("next Thursday");
```

Example straight from [PHP.net](http://us.php.net/strtotime), should work. And for the Thursday after that one you can do

```
$nextThursday= strtotime("next Thursday");
$secondThursday=strtotime("next Thursday",$nextThursday); // And so on
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/RoATnNfF)**

Comment: If today is Tuesday, will strtotime("next Thursday") give me date for this week's Thursday as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php
$next_thursday    =     strtotime("next Thursday");
$this_thurday     =     strtotime('thursday this week');
if($next_thursday==$this_thurday)
{ 
$numberOfWeeks = 1;
$next_thursday = $next_thursday + ($numberOfWeeks * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
}
echo date("Y/m/d", $this_thurday);
echo date("Y/m/d", $next_thursday);
?>
```

Comment: Wrong edit. Next Thursday and Thursday this week mean the same if today is before Thursday. Your code outputs `2014/01/23 2014/01/23`

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something like this and found the following in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13722929/4442529) from deceze:

```
(new DateTime('now'))->modify('+5 days')
```

I used this in the follow way:

```
$date = DateTime('15 apr 15');
$date->modify('next thursday');
var_dump($date);
```

This worked for me so I am putting this out there as another possibility for those looking.