# strtotime() for greater then 2038 years

Tags: php

I am trying to do the strtotime for date to convert it into :

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("10-12-2072"));
```

but it is not working correct as I have read on php.net that the Unix timestamp is start with 1970 and it will end on 2038 then how I can use my above code ??
any suggestion ?

Comment: you might need to take a look at [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) it has a Solutions part in its page!

Comment: This is one (of many) reason why we keep telling people to switch to DateTime objects, which have a date range that would keep cosmologists and palaeontologists happy (+/- 293 billion years).... or at least switch to a 64-bit OS and 64-bit PHP

Comment: Better use php DateTime object, Can handle all sorts of date types and is safe to use beyond 2038. Documentation and examples at http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: check my answer on how to use DateTime Class

Answer (score 1):

Parse the string to the `DateTime()` constructor and then format accordingly.
No need for any extra parsing logic here.
If this still doesn't work then check you are running a 64 bit system.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('10-12-2072');
$datetime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

From [DataTime](https://www.php.net/DateTime) Class, Use  [date_parse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) / [date_parse_from_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) in DateTime Class. Below is the Sample Snippets.

```
<?php
$date = "6.1.2009 13:00+01:00";
print_r(date_parse_from_format("j.n.Y H:iP", $date));
?>
```

Refer Similar Answer: [strtotime() DateTime class analog method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722878/strtotime-datetime-class-analog-method)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime()`. It will give you above 2038 year. Once you get the date and time together you can separate it by :

```
$datetime = "2012-10-19 18:19:56";
$Date = explode(" ",$datetime);
$date = $Date[0];
$time = $Date[1];
```

Now you can have the date only.

Good Luck!